# Find consecutive repeated nan in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the best way to find the maximum number of consecutive repeated nan in a numpy array?

Examples:

```
from numpy import nan
```

Input 1: `[nan, nan, nan, 0.16, 1, 0.16, 0.9999, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.101, nan, 0.16]`

Output 1: `3`

Input 2: `[nan, nan, 2, 1, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.101, nan, 0.16]`

Output 2: `4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def max_repeatedNaNs(a):
    # Mask of NaNs
    mask = np.concatenate(([False],np.isnan(a),[False]))
    if ~mask.any():
        return 0
    else:
        # Count of NaNs in each NaN group. Then, get max count as o/p.
        c = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] < mask[:-1]) - \
            np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] > mask[:-1])
        return c.max()
```

Here's an improved version -

```
def max_repeatedNaNs_v2(a):
    mask = np.concatenate(([False],np.isnan(a),[False]))
    if ~mask.any():
        return 0
    else:
        idx = np.nonzero(mask[1:] != mask[:-1])[0]
        return (idx[1::2] - idx[::2]).max()
```

Benchmarking in response to [`@pltrdy's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721674/find-consecutive-repeated-nan-in-a-numpy-array/41721813#comment70638536_41721813) -

```
In [77]: a = np.random.rand(10000)

In [78]: a[np.random.choice(range(len(a)),size=1000,replace=0)] = np.nan

In [79]: %timeit contiguous_NaN(a) #@pltrdy's solution
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop

In [80]: %timeit max_repeatedNaNs(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 µs per loop

In [81]: %timeit max_repeatedNaNs_v2(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: How to make something trivial a mess.

Comment: @pltrdy Appreciate you comment with that downvote. This solution is meant for performance. Would add some runtime test to testify that.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, but this function won't work when you have a array with zero Nan.

Comment: @volt Added IF-ELSE to catch such a case.

Comment: The guy is asking a pretty simple question, you give a complex over engineered answer. To my mind, it is therefore inappropriate. It's like talking about general relativity when a kid asks why the apple felt. Thats correct, thats not the "right answer" tho

Comment: @pltrdy Well this guy might be asking about performance when he mentioned about `best`. Adding timings soon.

Comment: I definetly agree with Divarkar, the solution may be more complex than it needs to be and I dislike any code containing `np.concatenate` but this will scale **very good** for bigger arrays.

Comment: @Divakar Could you also include my approach in your timings? :-)

Comment: Oh I do agree that it depend on his goal, i had no doubt about timing.
My point is that usually, keeping it simple and clear are greater benefit. May depend of course

Comment: @MSeifert Sure, coming up!

Comment: @pltrdy Or you could have made a better assumption when OP mentioned `best` :)

Comment: Wow, those timing results are savage. @Divakar Can you time mine as well please? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41722363/1636276

Comment: @Tagc MSeifert took the heavy work and posted timings in [`his post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41722059/3293881). Check those out!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you have numba but it's very handy (and fast) for such exceptional problems:

```
import numba as nb
import math

@nb.njit   # also works without but then it's several orders of magnitudes slower
def max_consecutive_nan(arr):
    max_ = 0
    current = 0
    idx = 0
    while idx < arr.size:
        while idx < arr.size and math.isnan(arr[idx]):
            current += 1
            idx += 1
        if current > max_:
            max_ = current
        current = 0
        idx += 1
    return max_
```

For your examples:

```
>>> from numpy import nan
>>> max_consecutive_nan(np.array([nan, nan, 2, 1, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.101, nan, 0.16]))
4

>>> max_consecutive_nan(np.array([nan, nan, nan, 0.16, 1, 0.16, 0.9999, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.101, nan, 0.16]))
3

>>> max_consecutive_nan(np.array([0.16, 0.16, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]))
22
```

Using the benchmark proposed by @Divarkar and ordered by performance (the complete code for the benchmarks can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/4ba7ed006428a0226a9d5b34b1bca1f0)):

```
arr = np.random.rand(10000)
arr[np.random.choice(range(len(arr)),size=1000,replace=0)] = np.nan
%timeit mine(arr)         # 10000 loops, best of 3: 67.7 µs per loop
%timeit Divakar_v2(arr)   # 1000 loops, best of 3: 196 µs per loop
%timeit Divakar(arr)      # 1000 loops, best of 3: 252 µs per loop
%timeit Tagc(arr)         # 100 loops, best of 3: 6.92 ms per loop
%timeit Kasramvd(arr)     # 10 loops, best of 3: 38.2 ms per loop
%timeit pltrdy(arr)       # 10 loops, best of 3: 70.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Oh, I don't have access to `numba`! Could you use my timing tests maybe?

Comment: @Divakar ok, I've included it. It's too bad that only so few people have numba :(

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Yeah.. I guess more people should explore/use it.

Comment: Interesting to see that the fastest solution was over 1000 times faster than the slowest.

Comment: If I could bother you one more time - I added a better version, which I think gives like `15%+` improvement over the earlier one. So, if not too much of work, could you add that into the timings of yours? :)

Comment: @Divakar I've edited the post, I will see if I can put the benchmark test into a gist to preserve it. Also it seems more like a 25% improvement instead of 15%. Great work!

Comment: @MSeifert Very kool! Again, really appreciate the time you have put into it!

Comment: @MSeifert : I post an improvement at your fine work.

Answer (score 1):

I posted another answer based on `itertools`, but I believe this one is better:

```
from itertools import groupby

from numpy import nan


def longest_nan_run(sequence):
    return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence) if key is nan), default=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    array1 = [nan, nan, nan, 0.16, 1, 0.16, 0.9999, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.101, nan, 0.16]
    array2 = [nan, nan, 2, 1, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.101, nan, 0.16]

    print(longest_nan_run(array1))  # 3
    print(longest_nan_run(array2))  # 4
    print(longest_nan_run([]))      # 0
    print(longest_nan_run([1, 2]))  # 0
```

Edit: This now handles the case where no `nan` values are present (thanks to MSeifert for pointing it out).

Comment: On performance level, @Divakar's solution will be better I guess

Comment: @pltrdy Probably - let's try it out :)

Comment: @Tagc When I did the benchmarks I've noticed that you should specify a `default` to catch cases where there is no `nan`: `max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence) if key is nan), default=0)`

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks! Updated. Also thanks for posting the timings.

Answer (score 1):

A performance improvement is possible, especially when a long nan sequences exists.
In these cases there is no need to test all the values .

with @MSeifert approach and notations, the array can be sweeped by step of `max_` instead of one, if any hole appear in a `max_` length block :

```
@nb.njit
def max_consecutive_nan2(arr):
    max_ = 0
    idx = 0
    while idx < arr.size:
        while idx < arr.size and math.isnan(arr[idx]): # amelioration
            max_ += 1
            idx  += 1
        while idx < arr.size - max_:
            idx2 = idx + max_
            while idx2>idx and math.isnan(arr[idx2]):
                idx2 -=1
            if idx2==idx: # record reached.
              idx = idx + max_ +1
              break # goto amelioration
            idx=idx2 # skip unuseful tests
        else : return max_         
    return max_ #case record at end.
```

Results :

```
arr = np.random.rand(10000)
arr[np.random.choice(range(len(arr)),size=4000,replace=0)] = np.nan

In [25]: max_consecutive_nan(arr)
Out[25]: 14

In [26]: max_consecutive_nan2(arr)
Out[26]: 14
```

And performances :

```
In [27]: %timeit max_consecutive_nan2(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.29 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit max_consecutive_nan(arr) # MSeifert
10000 loops, best of 3: 68.5 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.
Computational complexity is `O(n)` with `n = len(arr)`, space is `O(1)`

```
def contiguous_NaN(arr):
     count, max_count = 0, 0
     for e in arr:
         if np.isnan(e):
             count += 1
             max_count = max(max_count, count)
         else:
             count = 0

     return max_count
```

---

Edit: Please keep in mind that the point of your code is:

1. To work
2. To work with reasonible resources (time & space).
3. **To be easy to read and understand.**

Comment: And iterating over numpy arrays is definetly violating point 2: Because it's one of the **most inefficient** ways to process an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pltrdy, but when the final of the array is 'nan' this function return 0. Example: "[0.16, 0.16, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]" returned 0

Answer (score 0):

An other easy to read and understand way is to use strings, then `str.split` :

```
array2 = [nan, nan, 2, 1, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.101, nan, 0.16]
thestring=isnan(array2).tobytes().decode()
#'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00'
m=max(len(c) for c in thestring.split('\x00'))
# 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite efficiently in NumPy without using any loops.

If we call the sequence `x` then we can find the maximum number of consequtive `nan`'s with:

```
np.max(np.diff(np.concatenate(([-1], np.where(-np.isnan(x))[0], [len(x)]))) - 1)
```