# Why can itertools.groupby group the NaNs in lists but not in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nan

I'm having a difficult time to debug a problem in which the float `nan` in a `list` and `nan` in a `numpy.array` are handled differently when these are used in `itertools.groupby`:

Given the following list and array:

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

lst = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.16, 1, 0.16, 0.9999, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.101, np.nan, 0.16]
arr = np.array(lst)
```

When I iterate over the list the contiguous `nan`s are grouped:

```
>>> for key, group in groupby(lst):
...     if np.isnan(key):
...         print(key, list(group), type(key))
nan [nan, nan, nan] <class 'float'>
nan [nan] <class 'float'>
```

However if I use the array it puts successive `nan`s in different groups:

```
>>> for key, group in groupby(arr):
...     if np.isnan(key):
...         print(key, list(group), type(key))
nan [nan] <class 'numpy.float64'>
nan [nan] <class 'numpy.float64'>
nan [nan] <class 'numpy.float64'>
nan [nan] <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Even if I convert the array back to a list:

```
>>> for key, group in groupby(arr.tolist()):
...     if np.isnan(key):
...         print(key, list(group), type(key))
nan [nan] <class 'float'>
nan [nan] <class 'float'>
nan [nan] <class 'float'>
nan [nan] <class 'float'>
```

I'm using:

```
numpy 1.11.3
python 3.5
```

I know that generally `nan != nan` so why do these operations give different results? And how is it possible that `groupby` can group `nan`s at all?

Comment: Hm, I wonder what prompted this question. :)

Comment: What exactly is the question here: Why `groupby` shown this inconsistent behaviour, or how to work around it? And in the latter case, do you want `nan`s grouped or not?

Comment: Just if someone else is interested, the question was prompted when I tried to find out why [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41722363/5393381) worked when applied to a list but not when applied to an `np.array`.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm interested in an explanation why these differ.

Comment: `groupby` applied to a float dtype array may be close to useless unless `np.isclose` is used as `key`.

Comment: @hpaulj You're right but if one nan is present in the list casting it to an array will (when no dtype is specified) result in a float array. So it could make sense to use `groupby` on a float array containing "ints" (or as close to an integer value as a float can be) and nan.

Comment: Sorry, the binary `isclose` won't work as a key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python lists are just arrays of pointers to objects in memory. In particular `lst` holds pointers to the object `np.nan`:

```
>>> [id(x) for x in lst]
[139832272211880, # nan
 139832272211880, # nan
 139832272211880, # nan
 139832133974296,
 139832270325408,
 139832133974296,
 139832133974464,
 139832133974320,
 139832133974296,
 139832133974440,
 139832272211880, # nan
 139832133974296]
```

(`np.nan` is at 139832272211880 on my computer.)

On the other hand, NumPy arrays are just contiguous regions of memory; they are regions of bits and bytes that are interpreted as a sequence of values (floats, ints, etc.) by NumPy.

The trouble is that when you ask Python to iterate over a NumPy array holding floating values (at a `for`-loop or `groupby` level), Python needs to box these bytes into a proper Python object. It creates a brand new Python object in memory for each single value in the array as it iterates.

For example, you can see that that distinct objects for each `nan` value are created when `.tolist()` is called:

```
>>> [id(x) for x in arr.tolist()]
[4355054616, # nan
 4355054640, # nan
 4355054664, # nan
 4355054688,
 4355054712,
 4355054736,
 4355054760,
 4355054784,
 4355054808,
 4355054832,
 4355054856, # nan
 4355054880]
```

`itertools.groupby` is able to group on `np.nan` for the Python list because it checks for *identity* first when it compares Python objects. Because these pointers to `nan` all point at the same `np.nan` object, grouping is possible.

However, iteration over the NumPy array does not allow this initial identity check to succeed, so Python falls back to checking for equality and `nan != nan` as you say.

Answer (score 7):

The answers of [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724043/5393381) and [ajcr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724088/5393381) are correct, it's because the `nan`s in the list have the same `id` while they have different ids when they are "iterated over" in the numpy-array.

This answer is meant as a supplement for these answers.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> import numpy as np

>>> lst = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.16, 1, 0.16, 0.9999, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.101, np.nan, 0.16]
>>> arr = np.array(lst)

>>> for key, group in groupby(lst):
...     if np.isnan(key):
...         print(key, id(key), [id(item) for item in group])
nan 1274500321192 [1274500321192, 1274500321192, 1274500321192]
nan 1274500321192 [1274500321192]

>>> for key, group in groupby(arr):
...     if np.isnan(key):
...         print(key, id(key), [id(item) for item in group])
nan 1274537130480 [1274537130480]
nan 1274537130504 [1274537130504]
nan 1274537130480 [1274537130480]
nan 1274537130480 [1274537130480]  # same id as before but these are not consecutive

>>> for key, group in groupby(arr.tolist()):
...     if np.isnan(key):
...         print(key, id(key), [id(item) for item in group])
nan 1274537130336 [1274537130336]
nan 1274537130408 [1274537130408]
nan 1274500320904 [1274500320904]
nan 1274537130168 [1274537130168]
```

The problem is that Python uses the [`PyObject_RichCompare`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompare)-operation when comparing values, which only tests for object identity if `==` fails because it's not implemented. `itertools.groupby` on the other hand uses [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool) (see Source: [1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L88), [2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L318)) which tests for object identity **first and before `==` is tested**.

This can be verified with a small cython snippet:

```
%load_ext cython
%%cython

from cpython.object cimport PyObject_RichCompareBool, PyObject_RichCompare, Py_EQ

def compare(a, b):
    return PyObject_RichCompare(a, b, Py_EQ), PyObject_RichCompareBool(a, b, Py_EQ)

>>> compare(np.nan, np.nan)
(False, True)
```

The source code for `PyObject_RichCompareBool` reads like this:

```c
/* Perform a rich comparison with object result.  This wraps do_richcompare()
   with a check for NULL arguments and a recursion check. */

/* Perform a rich comparison with integer result.  This wraps
   PyObject_RichCompare(), returning -1 for error, 0 for false, 1 for true. */
int
PyObject_RichCompareBool(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, int op)
{
    PyObject *res;
    int ok;

    /* Quick result when objects are the same.
       Guarantees that identity implies equality. */
    /**********************That's the difference!****************/
    if (v == w) {
        if (op == Py_EQ)
            return 1;
        else if (op == Py_NE)
            return 0;
    }

    res = PyObject_RichCompare(v, w, op);
    if (res == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (PyBool_Check(res))
        ok = (res == Py_True);
    else
        ok = PyObject_IsTrue(res);
    Py_DECREF(res);
    return ok;
}
```

The object identity test (`if (v == w)` ) is indeed done before the normal python comparison `PyObject_RichCompare(v, w, op);` is used and mentioned in [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool):

> Note :
>
> If o1 and o2 are the same object, `PyObject_RichCompareBool()` will always return 1 for Py_EQ and 0 for Py_NE.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure whether this is the reason, but I just noticed this about the `nan` in `lst` and `arr`:

```
>>> lst[0] == lst[1], arr[0] == arr[1]
(False, False)
>>> lst[0] is lst[1], arr[0] is arr[1]
(True, False)
```

I.e., while all `nan` are inequal, the regular `np.nan` (of type `float`) are all the *same* instance, while the `nan` in the `arr` are *different* instances of type `numpy.float64`). So my guess would be that if no `key` function is given, `groupby` will test for identity before doing the more expensive equality check.

This is also consistent with the observation that is does not group in `arr.tolist()` either, because even though those `nan` are now `float` again, they are no longer the same instance.

```
>>> atl = arr.tolist()
>>> atl[0] is atl[1]
False
```

Comment: So `math.nan` is a singleton, and `np.nan` is a singleton, but accessing a `np.array` creates a temporary float that *isn't* a singleton? Mind blown.

Comment: @MarkRansom not only `np.array.__getitem__` creates a different object for nan when you want to access it. But every time you manually create a `nan` (for example `float('nan')`) a new _not-singleton_ nan is created. Fun fact: `np.nan is not math.nan`!