# Unique values from pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following `pandas.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan])

s
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

I want to find only unique values in this particular series using the built-in `set` function:

```
unqs = set(s)

unqs
{nan, 1.0, nan}
```

Why are there duplicate `NaN`s in the resultant set? Using a similar function (`pandas.unique`) does not produce this result, so what's the difference, here?

```
pd.unique(s)
array([ nan,   1.])
```

Comment: Because in Python `math.nan != math.nan`. It is one of the violations of the *reflexivity* contract an equality relation should have, but there are good reasons to do that here.

Comment: Is there a particular design reason for this? The result of that comparison is unintuitive.

Comment: more than unintuitive, it even violates the reflexivity constraint. The reason is that for instance `math.nan + 2` is also `math.nan`, but can you say that `x + 2 == x`?

Comment: Please, when working with pandas, use `s.unique()` or `s.value_counts()`.

Comment: I think this problem has been answered in various guises before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723419) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721635)). Basically Python creates new NaN objects when it iterates over the Series (like you point out) and Python tests for equal objects by id first, before falling back to `==`.

Comment: In your last snippet `(id(x[0]), id(x[1]))` you are comparing `nan` and `1.0` because `x[0]` is `nan` and `x[1]` is `1.0`.

Comment: @godaygo They would be different if both x[0] and x[1] referred to np.nan as well. Try with `arr = np.array([np.nan, np.nan])`, `id(arr[0])` and `id(arr[1])`. You'll get different id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false), and [JavaScript](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-problem-with-testing-for-nan-in-javascript.html), `nan` in numpy does not equal itself.

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

This means when the `set` constructor checks "do I have an instance of `nan` in this set yet?" it alwasy returns *`False`*

## So… why?

`nan` in both cases means "value which cannot be represented by 'float'". This means an attempt to convert it to float necessarily fails. It's also unable to be sorted, because there's no way to tell if `nan` is supposed to be larger or smaller than any number.

After all, which is bigger "cat" or 7? And is "goofy" == "pluto"?

## SO… what do I do?

There are a couple of ways to resolve this problem. Personally, I generally try to *fill* nan before processing: `DataFrame.fillna` will help with that, and I would always use `df.unique()` to get a set of unique values.

```
no_nas = s.dropna().unique()
with_nas = s.unique()
with_replaced_nas = s.fillna(-1).unique() # using a placeholder
```

(note: all of the above can be passed into the `set` constructor.

## What if I don't want to use the Pandas way?

There are reasons not to use Pandas, or to rely on native objects instead of Pandas. These should suffice.

Your other option is to **filter** and remove the `nan`.

```
unqs = set(item for item in s if not np.isnan(item))
```

You could also replace things inline:

```
placeholder = '{placeholder}' # There are a variety of placeholder options.
unqs = set(item if not np.isnan(item) else placeholder for item in s)
```

Comment: `"SO... what do I do?"` No, you really should be using pandas functions that are meant for things like this. Example, `s.dropna().unique()`, or `s.value_counts().index`, and so on.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Added the generally preferred Pandas approach, but since I don't know OP's original needs, I've added an additional section.

Comment: Looks better now :-)