# Why does 'groupby(x, np.isnan)' behave differently to 'groupby(x) if key is nan'?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nan

[Since we're on the topic of peculiarities surrounding numpy's `nan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723419/itertools-groupby-with-nans-gives-different-results-with-list-and-numpy-array), I've discovered something that I don't understand either. I'm posting this question mainly as an extension of MSeifert's since it seems there might be a common reason for both of our observations.

Earlier on, [I posted a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41722363/1636276) that involves using `itertools.groupby` on a sequence containing `nan` values:

```
return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence) if key is nan), default=0)
```

However, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41723561/1636276) on MSeifert's question linked above which shows an alternative way I might have formulated this algorithm:

```
return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence, np.isnan)), default=0)
```

**Experiment**

I've tested both of these variations with both lists and numpy arrays. The code and results are included below:

```
from itertools import groupby

from numpy import nan
import numpy as np


def longest_nan_run(sequence):
    return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence) if key is nan), default=0)


def longest_nan_run_2(sequence):
    return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence, np.isnan)), default=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nan_list = [nan, nan, nan, 0.16, 1, 0.16, 0.9999, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.101, nan, 0.16]
    nan_array = np.array(nan_list)

    print(longest_nan_run(nan_list))  # 3 - correct
    print(longest_nan_run_2(nan_list))  # 7 - incorrect
    print(longest_nan_run(nan_array))  # 0 - incorrect
    print(longest_nan_run_2(nan_array))  # 7 - incorrect
```

**Analysis**

- Of all four combinations, only checks against **lists** using the **original** function works as expected.
- The **modified** function (using `np.isnan`) seems to work the **same way** for both lists and arrays.
- The **original** function does not appear to find any `nan` values when checking **arrays**.

Can anyone explain these results? Again, as this question is related to MSeifert's, it's possible that an explanation of his results would explain mine too (or vice versa).

---

**Further Investigation**

To get a better picture of what's happening, I tried printing out the groups generated by `groupby`:

```
def longest_nan_run(sequence):
    print(list(list(group) for key, group in groupby(sequence) if key is nan))
    return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence) if key is nan), default=0)


def longest_nan_run_2(sequence):
    print(list(list(group) for _, group in groupby(sequence, np.isnan)))
    return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence, np.isnan)), default=0)
```

One fundamental difference (which in retrospect makes sense) is that the **original** function (using `if key is nan`) will filter out everything *except* `nan` values, so all generated groups will consist only of `nan` values, like this:

```
[[nan, nan, nan], [nan]]
```

On the other hand, the **modified** function will group all non-`nan` values into their own groups, like this:

```
[[nan, nan, nan], [0.16, 1.0, 0.16, 0.99990000000000001, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.10100000000000001], [nan], [0.16]]
```

This explains why the modified function returns `7` in both cases - it's considering values as either "`nan`" or "not `nan`" and returning the longest contiguous series of either.

This also means that I was wrong about my assumptions of how `groupby(sequence, keyfunc)` works, and that the modified function is not a viable alternative to the original.

I'm still not sure about the difference in results when running the original function on lists and arrays, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item access in numpy arrays behaves different than in lists:

```
nan_list[0] == nan_list[1]
# False
nan_list[0] is nan_list[1]
# True

nan_array[0] == nan_array[1]
# False
nan_array[0] is nan_array[1]
# False

x = np.array([1])
x[0] == x[0]
# True
x[0] is x[0]
# False
```

While the list contains references to the same object, numpy arrays 'contain' only a region of memory and create new Python objects on the fly each time an element is accessed. (Thank you user2357112, for pointing out the inaccuracy in phrasing.)

Makes sense, right? Same object returned by the list, different objects returned by the array - obviously `groupby` internally uses `is` for comparison... But wait, it's not that easy! Why does `groupby(np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3]))` work correctly?

The answer is buried in the the [itertools C source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c?view=markup), line 90 shows that the function [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool) is used for comparing two keys.

```
rcmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(gbo->tgtkey, gbo->currkey, Py_EQ);
```

Although this is basically equivalent to using `==` in Python, the docs note one speciality:

> **Note** If o1 and o2 are the same object, `PyObject_RichCompareBool()` will always return `1` for `Py_EQ` and `0` for `Py_NE`.

This means that actually this comparison is performed (equivalent code):

```
if o1 is o2:
    return True
else:
    return o1 == o2
```

So for lists, we have the same `nan` objects, which is identified as equal. In contrast, arrays give us different objects with value `nan`, which are compared with `==` - but `nan == nan` always evaluates as `False`.

Comment: "np.array contains different objects (with the same value)" - no, it doesn't contain objects at all. The objects are created on element access, so you'll even get False for `x[0] is x[0]`.

Comment: @kazemakase Thanks for your answer. :) I saw you post it as I was typing mine. Your answer provides details that mine doesn't and that I don't know about, so I'll be reading over it.

Comment: @Tagc you are welcome. It was an interesting question to dig into. Don't forget to refresh the page - I have edited the answer to improve the narrative and to incorporate user23...'s comment.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I've painted a clear enough picture for myself of what's going on.

There two factors at play here:

- My own misunderstanding of what the `keyfunc` argument did for `groupby`.
- The (much more interesting) story of how Python represents `nan` values within arrays and lists, which is best explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724043/1636276).

**Explaining the `keyfunc` factor**

From the [documentation on `groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes

From the [documentation on `np.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

> For scalar input, the result is a new boolean with value True if the input is NaN; otherwise the value is False.

Based on these two things, we deduce that when we set `keyfunc` as `np.isnan`, each element in the sequence passed to `groupyby` will be mapped to either `True` or `False`, depending on whether it is a `nan` or not. This means that the key function will only change at the boundary between `nan` elements and non-`nan` elements, and therefore that `groupby` will only split the sequence into contiguous blocks of `nan` and non-`nan` elements.

In contrast, the **original** function (which used `groupby(sequence) if key is nan`) will use the *identity function* for `keyfunc` (its default value). This naturally leads into the nuances of `nan` identity which is explained below (and in the linked answer above), but the important point here is that the `if key is nan` will filter out all groups keyed on non-`nan` elements.

**Explaining nuances in `nan` identity**

As better explained in the answer I linked above, all instances of `nan` that occur within Python's built-in lists seem to be **one and the same instance**. In other words, all occurrences of `nan` in lists point to the same place in memory. In contrast to this, `nan` elements are generated on the fly when using numpy arrays and so are all separate objects.

This is demonstrated using the code below:

```
def longest_nan_run(sequence):
    print(id(nan))
    print([id(x) for x in sequence])
    return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in groupby(sequence) if key is nan), default=0)
```

When I run this using the **list** defined in the original question, I obtain this output (identical elements are highlighted):

```
4436731128
[4436731128, 44436731128, 44436731128, 4436730432, 4435753536, 4436730432, 4436730192, 4436730048, 4436730432, 4436730552, 44436731128, 4436730432]
```

On the other hand, array elements seem to be handled in memory very differently:

```
4343850232
[4357386696, 4357386720, 4357386696, 4357386720, 4357386696, 4357386720, 4357386696, 4357386720, 4357386696,, 4357386720, 4357386696, 4357386720]
```

The function seems to alternate between two separate locations in memory for storing these values. Notice that none of the elements are identical to the `nan` used in the filter condition.

### Case Studies

We can now apply all this information we've gathered to the four separate cases used in the experiment to explain our observations.

**Original function with lists**

During this case, we use the default `identity` function as `keyfunc`, and we've seen that each occurrence of `nan` in lists are in fact all the same instance. The `nan` used in the filter conditional `if key is nan` is *also* identical to the `nan` elements in the list, causing `groupby` to break the list at appropriate places and only retain the groups containing `nan`. This is why this variant works and we obtain the correct result of `3`.

**Original function with arrays**

Again, we use the default `identity` function as `keyfunc`, but this time all `nan` occurrences - including the one in the filter conditional - point to different objects. This means that the conditional filter `if key is nan` will fail for *all* groups. Since we can't find the maximum of an empty collection, we fall back on the default value of `0`.

**Modified function with lists and arrays**

In both of these cases, we use `np.isnan` as `keyfunc`. This will cause `groupby` to split the sequence into contiguous sequences of `nan` and non-`nan` elements.

For the list/array we used for our experiment, the longest sequence of `nan` elements is `[nan, nan, nan]`, which has three elements, and the longest sequence of non-`nan` elements is `[0.16, 1, 0.16, 0.9999, 0.0001, 0.16, 0.101]`, which has 7 elements.

`max` will select the longer of these two sequences and return `7` in both cases.

Comment: "all instances of nan that occur within Python's built-in lists seem to be one and the same instance" - nah, that's just because you used the specific `numpy.nan` object for all the nans in your list. If you'd, say, made separate `float('nan')` calls for each nan, you'd have gotten different objects.

Comment: Also note that this already plays a role inside `groupby`. `list(groupby(nan_list))` gives different results than `list(groupby(nan_array))`.

Comment: @user2357112 So it is correct to say that built-in lists will simply *point* to the objects used to construct them, whereas numpy arrays sort of treat them as "templates" and (e.g.) call `copy(x)` on each element 'x' as it accesses it?

Comment: @Tagc: Lists always refer to the objects given as elements. NumPy arrays copy the numeric values directly into a non-object-oriented backing store and only construct objects to represent the elements if you try to retrieve them. (Unless you're using object arrays, which is usually a bad idea.)